# Thread-safe Phoenix Singleton class template with Boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, template, singleton, boost

I've implemented the phoenix-singleton as a class template with boost inspired by *Modern C++ Design*. The code compiles fine with MSVC 2013 - and it seems to work, but I'm new
to multi-threaded programming and Boost. Are there any pitfalls in the code? Improvements?

**TSingleton.h**

```
#ifndef TSINGLETON_H
#define TSINGLETON_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

template<typename T>
class TSingleton{
public:
    static T& getInstance();

protected:
    inline explicit TSingleton();
    TSingleton(const TSingleton&);
    TSingleton& operator=(const TSingleton&);
    virtual ~TSingleton();
    static void _CreateInstance();
    static void _Phoenix();
    static void _KillPhoenix();

    static boost::atomic<T*> _instance;
    static boost::atomic<bool> _destroyed;
    static boost::mutex _instantiation_mutex;
};



template<typename T>
boost::atomic<bool> TSingleton<T>::_destroyed = (boost::atomic<bool>) false;

template<typename T>
boost::atomic<T*> TSingleton<T>::_instance = (boost::atomic<T*>) nullptr;

template<typename T>
boost::mutex TSingleton<T>::_instantiation_mutex;

template<typename T>
TSingleton<T>::~TSingleton(){
    TSingleton::_destroyed = true;
    TSingleton::_instance = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
T& TSingleton<T>::getInstance(){
    T* tmp = TSingleton::_instance.load(boost::memory_order_consume);
    if (!tmp){
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock guard(TSingleton::_instantiation_mutex);
        tmp = TSingleton::_instance.load(boost::memory_order_consume);
        if (!tmp){
            if (TSingleton::_destroyed){
                TSingleton::_Phoenix();
            }else{
                TSingleton::_CreateInstance();
            }
            tmp = TSingleton::_instance.load(boost::memory_order_consume);
        }
    }
    return *tmp;
}

template<typename T>
void TSingleton<T>::_CreateInstance(){
    static T instance;
    TSingleton::_instance.store(&instance, boost::memory_order_release);
}

template<typename T>
void TSingleton<T>::_Phoenix(){
    TSingleton::_CreateInstance();
    new(TSingleton::_instance) T;
    std::atexit(TSingleton::_KillPhoenix);
    TSingleton::_destroyed = false;
}

template<typename T>
void TSingleton<T>::_KillPhoenix(){
    T* tmp = TSingleton::_instance.load(boost::memory_order_consume);
    tmp->~T();
    TSingleton::_destroyed = true;
    TSingleton::_instance = nullptr;
}

#endif // TSINGLETON_H
```

**Simple usage example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TSingleton.h"

class Foo{
public:
    void bar(){ std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Foo& myfoo = TSingleton<Foo>::getInstance();
    myfoo.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your question looks like an interesting implementation and I hope you get good reviews!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a threading specialist, so won't be able to tell you for sure if your code is 100% race condition free. However, there are a few other [code smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) that I would like to warn you about:

- Reserved names: A name starting with an underscore and an uppercase letter is [reserved in any scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654). `_CreateInstance`, `_Phoenix` and `_KillPhoenix` are not safe to be used, even inside a class.
- `inline` is redundant for a template class or function. The class is always inline, so you don't have to add the keyword.
- `explicit` makes no sense for a constructor that takes 0 arguments. You usually apply `explicit` if you have a constructor taking 1 argument and you wish to avoid an implicit conversion.
- Do you really plan on allowing classes to inherit from `TSingleton`? It doesn't seem like there is a need for that, since the singleton type is a template parameter. Maybe I'm missing something, but if it is not to be inherited, make all currently `protected` members `private` and remove `virtual` from the destructor.
- This initialization style is mighty strange: `_destroyed = (boost::atomic<bool>) false;` A plain assignment `_destroyed = false;` or using the constructor syntax: `_destroyed(false);` would be much better.
- When calling a static method or accessing a static variable of a class, inside the given class, prefixing the call with `ClassName` is optional. So you could, for example, simply use `_instance` instead of `TSingleton::_instance`.
- VS 2013 should have most if not all C++11 features and libraries working. So you could replace Boost with the new [threading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) and [atomics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) libraries to reduce dependencies.
- If you switch to C++11, you can [`delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) the copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: - `_destroyed = false;` does not work on VS13 (see [Initializing std::atomic_bool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750917/initializing-stdatomic-bool) ). I use Boost in my project anyway - but I could rewrite it for plain C++11 if rquested (but thats offtopic :).

Comment: @PatrickP - That's quite surprising. Well, according to the answers, you can still use the constructor initialization, which would be the most correct form anyway.

Comment: Already done. I will change the code according to your suggestions and update the question.

Comment: @PatrickP - You mentioned updating the question. Read this first: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765

Answer (score 2):

### Phenix Singelton: I hate this whole idea.

There are better ways of doing it.

The [classic singleton solves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065) most of your problems.

```
class S
{
    public:
        static S& getInstance()
        {
            static S    instance; // Guaranteed to be destroyed.
                                  // Instantiated on first use.
            return instance;
        }
    private:
        S() {};
        S(S const&);              // Don't Implement
        void operator=(S const&); // Don't implement
};
```

So the only thing you need to worry about is when the singleton is destroyed and you want to re-use it. Since the classic singelton is a static storage duration object it will be destroyed after `main()` exits. Thus the only time you need to worry about accessing a destroyed signelton is if you access it from the destructor of another static storage duration object (global variable).

This is not really a problem as you can force the singelton to live longer than your object by accessing it in the constructor. So simple rule. If you access a classic singelton from the destructor just make sure you access it in the constructor first (and then all your problems are solved).

Lot of description here: [Finding C++ static initialization order problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/335746/14065)

### Code Review

#### destructor?

You really want to set things to NULL when an object is destroyed!!!

```
template<typename T>
TSingleton<T>::~TSingleton(){
    TSingleton::_destroyed = true;
    TSingleton::_instance = nullptr;
}
```

This will cause this to Fail:

```
Foo& getMyFoo()
{
    TSingleton<Foo>   x;
    return x.getInstance();
}   // x goes out of scope here and resets the class members to null via detructor.
    // Yep I know this is not the use case you designed it for.
    // But this is still technically allowed.

void doWork()
{
   Foo&   x = getMyFoo();  // Reference to object.  // But the pointer that originally
                                                    // held it is now NULL (x is good)

   Foo&   y = getMyFoo();                           // Here you are forcing a 
                                                    // re-construction of your object but
                                                    // without the destructor being called.
                                                    // Which I am pretty sure is UB.
}
```

#### Shared lib problem.

This is not going to interact well with shared libraries on all systems.

I seem to remember (though I could be wrong here). That using this template technique is not going to react well to being used across multiple shared libraries. Because it is a template it is not going to be removed if you have multiple versions of this singelton in different shared libraries.

@glampert has mentioned all the other points I want to mention.

Comment: I can understand that you disrelish the Phoenix Singleton. But this is imho the *lesser of the evils*-solution for my problem. I need the singleton for managing global states seamlessly from c++ and an embedded python environment throughout different threads. as if this wasn't enough, in python you can create derivate from the singleton or use the singleton indirect from another c++ static through a python call - so I have no control about the lifetime with the *accessing it in the constructor* method you've mentioned.

Comment: `TSingleton<T>::~TSingleton(){...}` I agree - design flaw. *Shared lib problem:* I agree in general case, but the Singleton is in my context only used in main-binary and is not used in extern code.